# Manual recompile stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recompile

How can I recompile manually a stored procedure in SQL Server? Is just like a `drop` and `create`?

I know can do it with an option in the create statement `(WITH RECOMPILE)`, and it will be recompiled every execution, and executing `sp_recompile @procedureName`, which will only recompile it the next time it executes, but how can I recompile it manually without these two approaches?

Comment: [ALTER PROCEDURE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225939(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: DROP/CREATE also compiles the proc the next time it is executed so I think sp_recompile is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Stored Procedures are compiled when they are "first" executed. "First" meaning, they have no chached plan. All you can do is invalidate the cache. In SQL-Server, there is no way to force compilation other than calling it.

(BTW, this is unlike Oracle, where you may have gotten the idea from)

In our application, we maintain a script called "run_sample_statements.sql". This contains a number of representative queries and procedure calls to cause compilation and caching. We used that after maintenance and index-rebuilds to test/precache the system before we release it for the users again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do it is to find the plan handle by querying

```
Select st.Plan_handle 
from 
sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
    CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) st 
WHERE text like '% your proc name %'
```

Then DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (plan_handle)

This method is effectively the same as sp_recompile.